# Why is $M_{f\geq 0}$ a manifold with boundary?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, morse-theory

I'm studying Morse theory and I found this fact:

Let be $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a Morse function on a m-manifold $M$. Suppose $0$ is not a critical value of $f$. Then $M_{f\geq 0}=\lbrace p\in M | f(p)\geq 0\rbrace$ is a manifold with boundary and $\partial M = M_{f=0} = \lbrace p\in M | f(p)= 0\rbrace$.

I have problems with this. I know that points in $M_{f=0}$ must not be interior points, but the other points in $M_{f\geq 0}$ are interior points. However, I don't know why points in $M_{f=0}$ are boundary points...

Comment: Think about the sentence "Suppose $0$ is not a critical value of $f$."

Comment: I don't see it yet...

Comment: In a neighborhood of every point of $f=0$ you can choose new coordinates so that $f=x_n$.

Comment: Ohhh I think I get it @tedshifrin. That is possible because rank theorem right?

Comment: It follows immediately from the inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p$ is an interior point of the submanifold $M_{f\ge0}$. Pick a chart around $p$ so that we're working with a function $f : \mathbf{R}^m \to \mathbf{R}$ having the following properties:

1. $(df)_0 \neq 0$
2. $f(0) = 0$
3. $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$

Conditions 2 and 3 say that $0$ is a local minimum (a global minimum on a local chart) so how could the derivative be non-zero?

Comment: I don't think I understand your idea... The derivative is non-zero because $0$ is not a critical value

Comment: @3435 I'm mapping $p$ to $0$ in the chart and yes, because it's not a critical value.